# How to make such delay which don't apply on specific operation only first time.. But It should apply later? C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, delay

I had a function which update the database by every second (as continuously data coming by some Network) I wanted to put delay on that updating function.. As it would update database table by every 5 minutes..
Here is my Code

```
 if (ip==StrIp)
{
Task.Delay(300000).ContinueWith(_=> 
{                        //I'm Using Task.Delay to make delay

var res= from i in dc.Pins //LINQ Query
where i.ip== ip
select i;
for each (var p in res)
{
p.time= System.DateTime.Now,
p.temperature= temp,
.
. //some other values
. 
};
datacontext.submitChanges();

});
}
```

It is working and updating data by every 5 minutes, Now I want that data should update immediately only first time when application start but after that It should update after every 5 minutes.. But Right now my code isn't doing that.. 
How can I make such delay which ignore the operation first time, but apply on upcoming data iterations..?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flag to determine whether it is the first time your method is called, e.g.:

```
private uint _counter = 0;
public YourMethod()
{
    if (ip == StrIp)
    {
        Action<Task> action = _ =>
        {
            var res = from i in dc.Pins //LINQ Query
                      where i.ip == ip
                      select i;
            //...
            datacontext.submitChanges();
        };

        if (_counter++ == 0)
            action();
        else
            Task.Delay(300000).ContinueWith(action);

    }
}
```

Comment: @BilalTahir: Please remember to accept the answer to close the question, if your original issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the inner logic of the task into a function/method (refactoring of [VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method?view=vs-2017)  or [R#](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Extract_Method.html) can to this automatically) and call the new function/method at start and on the interval.

I personally would go into another direction:

Have a in-memory queue that gets filled with data as it comes into your app. Then I would have a thread/task etc. which checks the queue every 5 minutes and updates the database accordingly. Remember to lock the queue for updates (concurrency). The [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) of .Net is one way to do it.